# How to work with custom dimension in Google Analytics v3 for Android app

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to make an app, in which a user can search city names. When city names not found, that city name will be tracked by Google Analytics.

For that I have created a custom dimension by following image in Google Analytics:

[image]

and also :

[image]

I have the following code in my app when word is not found:

```
    EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker
                                        .getInstance(mActivity);
                                easyTracker.set(
                                        Fields.customDimension(1),
                                        cityNameWhichAreNotFound);
                                easyTracker.send(MapBuilder
                                        .createAppView()
                                        .build());
```

But I am not getting the missing city names. Can anybody help me?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you want to just check the city names that are not found you can do that by events also.

I am doing in that way only eg:-

```
mTracker.sendEvent("SEARCH_CATEGORY",
                    "SEARCH_ACTION", cityNameWhichAreNotFound, 0L);
```

By, doing this you will be able to see the list of cities that were searched and not found in your Google Analytics under `Behavior->Events->Overview`

Comment: Thanks, I will try with this also, but have u any idea about that "Custom Dimension and Matrix" about implementation?

Comment: No, I was looking at it previously but due to its complexity I left it and applied this simple approach :)

Comment: Ok, I have also tried but couldn't find, there is no well documents also :(

Comment: yeah, document don't look to be user-friendly and its was costing too much time.